# If Not or StrCmp Error? Received Runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, if-statement, strcmp

**What Im trying to do:** Copy last 3 write ups from other sheets (j). The other sheets have a header, but if there are no write ups itll grab the header then error the other 2. I need it to fill the cells on the active sheet to say "No Writeups" if it trys pulling the header as a write up and stop so it doesnt error.

**What I tried to do:** In Cells(1,1) the header reads "Date". As K searches through column 1, I attempted to do a strComp? for the "Date" text? bc integers and strings dont compare well?

I'm getting a runtime error `1004`?

```
Dim FirstLine As String
Dim NewestEntry As Integer

   FirstLine = 6

Dim GrabbedDate As String

For j = 0 To 20 '(20) Tail Tabs/Number of Tabs

        NewestEntry = Worksheets(Tail(j)).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

    For k = NewestEntry To NewestEntry - 2 Step -1
                
            GrabbedDate = Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 1).Text
            
            If StrComp(GrabbedDate, "Date") = 0 Then
                    k = 0
            
                If Not k = 1 Then
                
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 1).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 4)  'Date
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 4).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 5)  'Code
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 5).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 6)  'Pilot
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 8).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 7)  'Start Up
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 11).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 8) 'Airboorne
                    Worksheets(Tail(j)).Cells(k, 14).Copy Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 9) 'Shutdown
                    
                    FirstLine = FirstLine + 1
                    
                Else
                 If k = 1 Then
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 4).Value = ""                  'Date
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 5).Value = ""                  'Code
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 6).Value = ""                  'Pilot
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 7).Value = "No Write Up"       'Start Up
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 8).Value = "No Write Up"       'Airboorne
                    Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(FirstLine, 9).Value = "No Write Up"       'Shutdown
                    
                    FirstLine = FirstLine + 1
                
                End If
                End If
            End If

        Next k
    Next j
```

Comment: The way I read your code, you are comparing the ***text value*** from `GrabbedDate` with the string `Date`. What is the date you want to make the comparison to?

Comment: @PeterT The `Date` is supposed to be what ever date `NewestEntry` would pull up. The `NewestEntry` is supposed to pull the most recent date. Would I need to adjust the range `NewestEntry` to fix it,  maybe?

Comment: Your `GrabbedDate` value is probably just fine. What date do you want to compare it to? Right now, you are comparing (as an example) `05/31/2022` to the string `Date`. The `"Date"` in `StrComp` is exactly that string, not an actual date from a cell or range.